# duplicate symbol errors in Xcode when linking to a library from two different source files

Tags: c, xcode

I created a command line project in Xcode. The project contains a "client.h", "client.c" and a "snap7.h".
The "snap7.h" has all the definitions of a dynamic library called "libsnap7.so".

The "client.h" includes the "snap7.h" and I am able to build an executable.

But when I want to use the "snap7.h" in further headers, for example "bitfunctions.h", then the linker shows hundreds of errors like:

```
duplicate symbol _errLibXXX in:
../x86_64/client.o
../x86_64/bitfunctions.o
```

A duplicate symbol in the "snap7.h" file would be for example:

```
const int errLibInvalidParam  = -1;
const int errLibInvalidObject = -2;
```

The "snap7.h" is included in "bitfunctions.h" like this:

```
#ifndef S7SnapClient_bitfunctions_h
#define S7SnapClient_bitfunctions_h

#include "snap7.h"
...
#endif
```

When I link this code on a linux machine, there are also the duplicate symbol errors, but I can suppress them with the linker option "-z muldefs" in the makefile. Is there a similar feature which I can use in Xcode, or any other suggestions how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What fiendish things are being done in that header? it sounds liker they're either declaring global variables or global functions sans-inlining? Have you tracked that down? Just curious. I'm unfamiliar with ignoring duplicates link symbols in Xcode primarily because I try to avoid them in the first place.

Comment: I edited my question which shows definitions of the "snap7.h" which the linker complains to be duplicate.

Comment: if you have any control over that header at all you can static those two vars `static const ...` Or tuck them in an `enum` rather than using `const int` (which frankly I would prefer). Sure hope you have the freedom to modify those.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can build the project now. So the keyword "static" means that the symbol for the 'errLibInvalidParam' constant won't be exported by the linker, and so the project doesn't has duplicate symbols?

Comment: No, it means *every* translation unit that includes that header gets their *own* copy of that variable. Not entirely terrible since it is just a `const` id, so it is unlikely it is being used by address somewhere, but to be safe it should be a enum instead. You can find out about both in any decent C/C++ text.